# embedded wpf textbox does not accept input

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, textbox

I put a wpf textbox inside a combobox to allow the user to enter a custom setting.  I can read the keypress in the keydown event, but the text in the textbox does not change.  What am I missing?

```
<ComboBoxItem Name="GridSizeCustom">
  <StackPanel Height="30"
              Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Text="Grid Size (8 - 200)"
           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
           VerticalAlignment="Top"
           Margin="0"
           />
    <TextBox Name="GridSizeBox"
             KeyDown="test"
             Width="50"
             />
      </StackPanel>
    </ComboBoxItem>
```

I step through this event handler when I press a key, but no change to the textbox text:

```
public void test(Object sender, KeyboardEventArgs e) {

int x = 0;

  }
```

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: I tried your code and it works fine. Can you explain you issue a little bit more?

Comment: No repro.  Post xaml or code that shows the problem.

Comment: Hans, that is the code.  The text box apparently receives the keystroke because the test function is executed.  Be that as it may, the text in the textbox does not change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standardised way to let the user enter their own text is to have what WPF calls an 'editable' ComboBox:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.iseditable.aspx

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True"> ...
```

Hope that helps, I can feel your pain trying to find a way around the focus/input system!